# Selenium cannot find tag

Tags: python, selenium

Why this Python code for this particular URL cannot find  tag? In the Chrome dev tool you can see that  tag exists. I already tried to use different waits without any success.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:/Work/IdeaProjects/web_loaders/movie_scraper/chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

url = 'https://fmovies.is/film/gilmore-girls-4.krm6'
print('opening %s' % url)
driver.get(url)
content = driver.find_element_by_id('player').find_element_by_class_name('cover')
content.click()
print('after click')
src = WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'video'))
).get_attribute('src')
```

@DebanjanB, I skipped code for searching video "Gilmore Girls" because it is not concern to this issue. According to you question. Please open the site https://fmovies.is. Enter in the search bar "Gilmore Girls" and press . Click on the first found item. Browser opens the URL https://fmovies.is/film/gilmore-girls-6.mwo7. In this page you can see empty "player" with play button. Please notice that current opened link is not the streaming link. Please click on the play icon. The browser will open the new link and starts streaming video. I am trying to extract this last link. If in the Chrome you press "Select an element" button and choose streaming player then you will see  tag in "Elements" tab. Line you are asking for is simply trying to find this tag. Selenium's explicit waiting is used there

Comment: Is the tag is inside any frame or iframe tags?

Comment: @osya Can you consider updating us your exact manual step after you access the URL? Thanks

Comment: Video is inside an iframe. we need to switch the frame before accessing the inside content.driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

Comment: If you open this site in Chrome dev tool then <video> tag is not in <iframe>

Comment: @DebanjanB I open Chrome dev tool, start video. Then press "Select an element" button and click on the video player. Then I see <video> tag

Comment: @osya Thanks :) I am not asking what you are doing. My question is what are your Manual Steps which you are trying to automate?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am trying to scrape streaming URLs for bunch of movies

Comment: @osya You need to update me the exact manual steps you are trying to perform through your Automation script. Else I am not able to understand the sequence of events from your Question. Thanks

Comment: First I crawl IMDB to get a bunch of videos with their attributes (title,genre,release date, etc). Then I take title for every video and use it to search on the site https://fmovies.is/ to extract streaming link for this video. In the source code above I searched the streaming link for the video "Gilmore Girls"

Comment: How and where in your code are you searching `video "Gilmore Girls"`? Can you help me to understand what steps are you doing through this block of code: content = driver.find_element_by_id('player').find_element_by_class_name('cover')
content.click()
print('after click')
src = WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'video'))
).get_attribute('src')

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you get tag for url you have used in example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://gomovies.to/film/gilmore-girls-a-year-in-the-life-season-1-18045/'


print('opening %s' % url)
driver.get(url)
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('mvi-cover')
content.click()
print('after click')

src = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="media-player"]//video'))
)
print src.get_attribute('src')
```

The output will be like this:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/osya.py
opening https://gomovies.to/film/gilmore-girls-a-year-in-the-life-season-1-18045/
after click
http://c5s1.vsharing.ru/movies09/Series/2016/11/27/Gilmore.Girls.2016.S01E01.720p.WEBRip.x264-TheRival.mp4?h=sd8ZYN1c0xLL5D8qmxARSg&e=1498145815
```

Comment: There are no such issues with the site https://gomovies.to which you are using. This issue is specific for the https://fmovies.is site